# Include google analytics tag to django admin without changing the template for every page

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to include the google-analytics javascript snippet easily into the django admin page ? (django 1.10)

I would like to do that without creating a custom template for each of the admin page, just insert the script in the all admin.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the base admin page and put the tag there. Inside Template Directory, create a folder name `admin`, inside that, create a `base_site.html`. That `base_site.html` might look like this:

```
    {% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}

    {% load static %}
    {% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }} google analytics codes {% endblock %}
```