# Track django admin with Google Analytics

Tags: django, google-analytics, django-admin

What is the fastest way to put all admin pages of a Django app under Google Analytics/TagManager?

**EDIT**
A possible solution is here, but actually my question is about evaluating and comparing all the possible solutions: [Include google analytics tag to django admin without changing the template for every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412352/include-google-analytics-tag-to-django-admin-without-changing-the-template-for-e)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include google analytics tag to django admin without changing the template for every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412352/include-google-analytics-tag-to-django-admin-without-changing-the-template-for-e)

Comment: Thank you ruddra! I edited the description of the quesiton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do it

- Extend django.contrib.admin.templates.admin.base.html template in your project and then add Analytical code to this extended base.html template.

```
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}
{% load static %}  
{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }} 
google analytics code here
{% endblock %}
```

- Add Google Analytics code to custom JS and then add this JS as Media to ModelAdmin to track model admin. For this approach, you have to add this custom js to every modeladmin. This could be useful if you want to track a different model under the different Google Analytics account.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I think the first approach is the best one for my issue, as I need to ensure *all* admin templates are included. So this answer is the best, green check!